# Multiple roots of polynomials with coefficients $\pm 1$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, sequences-and-series

**Question P.** *Can a polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^ma_nx^n$ with coefficients $a_n\in\{-1,1\}$ (and $P(1)=0$) have a multiple root in the interval $(\tfrac12,1)$?*

Also I am interested in a similar question for analytic functions.

**Question A.** *Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ a series with coefficients $a_n\in\{-1,1\}$ such that $\sup_{m\in\mathbb N}|\sum_{n=0}^ma_i|<\infty$. Can the analytic function $f$ have a multiple root in the interval $(0,1)$?*

Comment: If we had an example in question P without extra condition $P(1)=0$, we can reach it by multiplying $P$ by $1-x^{m+1}$. Also this yields a positive answer to question $A$ by a similar reasoning

Comment: Regarding P: even without the $P(1)=0$ restriction, up to $m=20$, there are no multiple roots at all for $m$ even, while for $m$ odd all multiple roots that may occur are $m+1$st roots of unity.

Comment: Another thing about P: for each odd $m=2n-1$ there are two $P$'s with multiple roots, namely $\frac{(1-x^n)^2}{1-x}=1+x+...+x^{n-1}-x^n-x^{n+1}-...-x^{2n-1}$ and $\frac{(1-(-x)^n)^2}{1+x}=1-x+...+(-x)^{n-1}-(-x)^n-(-x)^{n+1}-...-x^{2n-1}$, and for $n$ prime these seem to be the only ones (again, checked experimentally up to $m=21$); but for $n$ not prime there are very many. Numbers of such polynomials go like $0,0,0,2,0,2,0,6,0,2,0,62,0,2,0,518,0,134,0,5452,0,2,...$

Comment: Such polynomials (series) are called *[Littlewood polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_polynomial) (series)*. Vader in Theorem 7.1  of “[Real roots of Littlewood polynomials](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Real-roots-of-Littlewood-polynomials-Sterk/423d9491444b8803c16268213f0e1b9fe4fb0530)” showed that a Littlewood polynomial of even degree has no real roots.

Comment: Moreover, in Appendix C was proposed the Mathematica document “which creates all combinations of Littlewood polynomials up until a give degree $l$ and evaluates for each of these polynomials whether there exist values for which both the function and its derivative equals 0. Having run this program for $l = 13$ (it takes much more computation time when $l$ gets bigger), we see that the only values that appear to sometimes be a double zero, are  $-1$ and $1$. The above strongly suggests that double zero's simply do not exist, except  $-1$ and $1$”.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Wait, but $x^2+x-1$ has a real root

Comment: [Double roots of random Littlewood polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2034) by Peled et al. seems relevant, although at first glance it does not directly answer the question. Near the end of the paper, they say they do not know if there exists a Littlewood polynomial with at least one non-cyclotomic double root.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Oops, I meant "has no multiple real roots". Sorry.

Comment: @AlexRavsky ah, then this is true not only for real roots: for even degree, a Littlewood polynomial $P$ has no multiple root even over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (because the derivative of $(x-1)P$ has only zero roots).

Comment: @TimothyChow, $(z^{18} + 2z^{15} + 2z^{13} + z^{12} + 2z^{11} + 3z^{10} + 3z^8 + 2z^7 + z^6 + 2z^5 + 2z^3 + z^2 + 1)(z^2 + 1)(z - 1)(z^3 - z - 1)^2$ and $(z^{18} + 2z^{15} + 2z^{13} + z^{12} + 3z^{10} + z^8 + 2z^7 + z^6 + 2z^5 + 2z^3 + z^2 + 1)(z^2 + 1)(z - 1)(z^3 - z - 1)^2$ are Littlewood polynomials with a non-cyclotomic repeated cubic factor.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you very much for your comment. You can write down it as an answer and I will accept it, which will allow me to close this question.

Comment: I can go one better, with a root that's actually in the bounds you asked about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Question P.** *Can a polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^ma_nx^n$ with coefficients $a_n\in\{-1,1\}$ (and $P(1)=0$) have a multiple root in the interval $(\tfrac12,1)$?*

Yes. The following four Littlewood polynomials:

- $z^{27} + z^{26} + z^{25} + z^{24} + z^{23} - z^{22} - z^{21} + z^{20} + z^{19} + z^{18} - z^{17} - z^{16} - z^{15} - z^{14} - z^{13} - z^{12} - z^{11} - z^{10} + z^9 + z^8 - z^7 + z^6 - z^5 + z^4 - z^3 + z^2 + z - 1 = (z^{18} + z^{16} + 2z^{15} + 2z^{13} + z^{12} + 2z^{11} + 3z^{10} + 3z^8 + 2z^7 + z^6 + 2z^5 + 2z^3 + 1)(z^2 + 1)(z - 1)(z^3 + z^2 - 1)^2$
- $z^{27} + z^{26} + z^{25} - z^{24} - z^{23} - z^{22} + z^{21} - z^{20} - z^{19} + z^{18} + z^{17} - z^{16} - z^{15} + z^{14} + z^{13} - z^{12} - z^{11} - z^{10} - z^9 - z^8 + z^7 + z^6 - z^5 + z^4 - z^3 + z^2 + z - 1 = (z^{21} - z^{20} + 2z^{19} - 2z^{18} + z^{17} + z^{16} - 3z^{15} + 3z^{14} - 2z^{13} + 2z^{11} - 4z^{10} + 4z^9 - 2z^8 - z^7 + 3z^6 - 4z^5 + 2z^4 - z^3 - z^2 + z - 1)(z^3 + z^2 - 1)^2$
- $z^{27} + z^{26} + z^{25} + z^{24} + z^{23} - z^{22} - z^{21} + z^{20} - z^{19} - z^{18} - z^{17} + z^{16} - z^{15} + z^{14} + z^{13} - z^{12} - z^{11} - z^{10} - z^9 - z^8 + z^7 + z^6 - z^5 + z^4 - z^3 + z^2 + z - 1 = (z^{18} + z^{16} + 2z^{15} + 2z^{13} + z^{12} + 2z^{11} + z^{10} + 3z^8 + z^6 + 2z^5 + 2z^3 + 1)(z^2 + 1)(z - 1)(z^3 + z^2 - 1)^2$
- $z^{27} + z^{26} + z^{25} - z^{24} - z^{23} - z^{22} + z^{21} + z^{20} + z^{19} + z^{18} - z^{17} + z^{16} - z^{15} - z^{14} - z^{13} + z^{12} - z^{11} - z^{10} - z^9 - z^8 + z^7 + z^6 - z^5 + z^4 - z^3 + z^2 + z - 1 = (z^{18} + z^{16} + 2z^{13} - z^{12} + 2z^{11} + z^{10} + 3z^8 + z^6 + 2z^5 + 2z^3 + 1)(z^2 + 1)(z - 1)(z^3 + z^2 - 1)^2$

all have repeated factor $z^3 + z^2 - 1$ with root $z \approx 0.75488$.

Comment: Did you found them by exhaustive search or some other methods? Are these of smallest degree?

Comment: @Somnium, exhaustive search, and yes.

Comment: Wow. So mysterious!

Comment: I've searched as far as I'm going to go. There are 16 Littlewood polynomials of degree 27 which have repeated non-cyclotomic roots: 4 each for 4 cubic repeated factors. There are none of degrees 29, 31, or 33, which I find mildly surprising.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, only some sort of evidence for A, hence community wiki.
There seems to be an algorithm that produces a sequence of polynomials $(P_n)$ like in P, with $P_0=1$, $P_{n+1}=P_n\pm x^{n+1}$, $n\geqslant0$, and with $P_n$ having a local minimum at $m_n$ such that the sequence of $m_n$ converges to $\approx0.7257794$ while $P_n(m_n)$ tends to 0.

You do this: let $P_6=1-x-x^2-x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$; it has a nice local minimum at $m_6\approx0.719842$. Now iterate the following procedure. Find minima of $P_n+x^{n+1}$, $P_n-x^{n+1}$ in the vicinity of $m_n$. Compare absolute values of these two polynomials at these minima. Choose for $P_{n+1}$ the one with smaller absolute value (and for $m_{n+1}$ where that value is attained).

Experimentally, these values become quite small quickly. For example, $P_{500}(m_{500})$ is about $1.644734\times 10^{-70}$.

Of course there is no control of the sequence $P_n(1)$ which is required to remain bounded. In fact $P_3(1)=-2$, $P_7(1)=2$, while $P_n(1)$ is either $-1$, $0$ or $1$ for all other $n$ up to $500$.

Comment: Is any periodicity in the sequence of pluses and minuses, found by this algorithm?

Comment: @TarasBanakh None that I could detect. It goes like 1 plus, 3 minuses, 4 pluses, 2 minuses, 2 pluses, 2 minuses, 1 plus, $1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1,...$

Comment: Maybe the pattern of signs can be regularized keeping convergences of $(m_n)$ to some $m_\infty$ and $(P_n(m_n))$ to $0$? I also note that if we require that $ P_n(1)$ is either −1, 0 or 1 for all $n\ge N$ if follows that for all these $n$  if $P_n(1)\ne 0$ then $P_{n+1}=P_n-P_n(1)x^{n+1}$, so it remains to provide the sign for  $x^{n+1}$ only when $P_n(1)=0$, that is for odd $n$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Would be great, but I do not see how to formulate an appropriate algorithm. What to choose? Depending on what?

Comment: @AlexRavsky At least it seems that forcing periodicity cannot work. Eventually periodic Littlewood series are of the form $P_n+x^{n+1}\frac{P_m}{1-x^{m+1}}$ where $P_n$ and $P_m$ are Littlewood polynomials of degrees $n$ and $m$ respectively. Experimentally, it seems that none of these have any multiple roots.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Oh no sorry, there are such, starting from $m=7$. For example,$$1+x\frac{1-x-x^2-x^3-x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7}{1-x^8}=\frac{(1-x)(1+x)^2}{1+x^4}$$

Comment: @AlexRavsky I now checked up to $\max(m,n)\leqslant10$, the only double zeros are at roots of unity. Of course $10$ is not much, but still...

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727194/a-few-conjectured-limits-of-products-involving-the-thue-morse-sequence) MSE question suggests that a required pattern can be like Thue–Morse sequence: “Let's define the signed [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) $t_n$ by the recurrence $t_0 = 1, \quad t_n = (-1)^n \, t_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor},$ or by the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_n \, x^n=\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-x^{2^n}\right)$”.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for the interesting suggestion! It indeed seems to come close. The series $1-x-x^2-x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7\prod_{n\geqslant0}(1-x^{2^n})$ has a local minimum at $\approx0.71975189$ with value $\approx-0.000975414$